# Showing multiple AdvancedMarkerElements with custom content

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have four pins on my map:

```
async function initMap() {
  const {PinElement} = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker")
  const {AdvancedMarkerElement} = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker")
  const {Map} = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 17.0969451, lng: -89.0734218 },
    zoom: 9,
    mapId: 'my_map',
  });

  const L2083875 = { lat: 17.1010277, lng: -89.0770841 };
  const marker0 = new AdvancedMarkerElement({position: L2083875, map: map, });

  const L615687 = { lat: 17.1074, lng: -89.07398 };
  const marker1 = new AdvancedMarkerElement({position: L615687, map: map, });

  const L614723 = { lat: 17.09582, lng: -89.06938 };
  const marker2 = new AdvancedMarkerElement({position: L614723, map: map, });

  const L5421822 = { lat: 17.0835327, lng: -89.0732431 };
  const marker3 = new AdvancedMarkerElement({position: L5421822, map: map, });
}
```

This works correctly and displays four markers with the default "content".

I would like to display two pins in one color, and two pins in another color, so I added two `PinElement`s and specified the `content` for each marker, per https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/basic-customization#change_the_background_color.

```
  const pinGlyph0 = new PinElement({
    background: "#EB3324",
    borderColor: "#EB3324",
  });

  const pinGlyph1 = new PinElement({
    background: "#FFFD55",
    borderColor: "#FFFD55",
  });

  const L2083875 = { lat: 17.1010277, lng: -89.0770841 };
  const marker0 = new AdvancedMarkerElement({position: L2083875, map: map, content: pinGlyph0.element,});

  const L615687 = { lat: 17.1074, lng: -89.07398 };
  const marker1 = new AdvancedMarkerElement({position: L615687, map: map, content: pinGlyph0.element,});

  const L614723 = { lat: 17.09582, lng: -89.06938 };
  const marker2 = new AdvancedMarkerElement({position: L614723, map: map, content: pinGlyph1.element,});

  const L5421822 = { lat: 17.0835327, lng: -89.0732431 };
  const marker3 = new AdvancedMarkerElement({position: L5421822, map: map, content: pinGlyph1.element,});
```

I expected two markers in the first color and two markers in the second color, but only one marker of each color is displayed. Why am I only getting one marker per color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You must assign a new `PinElement` for each `AdvancedMarker` content props

A DOM element can only be in one place at a time. Since a `PinElement` represents a seperate DOM element, you cannot reuse it for each `AdvancedMarker` elements just like how you have shown in your code. Because if you do so, it will just remove it from its first parent and append it to the next one, which explains why only 2 markers are shown when you reuse the two `PinElement` in your sample.

[Reference Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/advanced-markers#AdvancedMarkerElementOptions.content) specifically says this:

> *"`AdvancedMarkerElement` does not clone the passed-in DOM element. Once the DOM element is passed to an `AdvancedMarkerElement`, passing the same DOM element to another `AdvancedMarkerElement` will move the DOM element and cause the previous `AdvancedMarkerElement` to look empty."*

So the solution would be to create a new `PinElement` unique for each `AdvancedMarker` instantiation like so:

```
const pinGlyphRed1 = new PinElement({
  background: "#EB3324",
  borderColor: "#EB3324"
});

const pinGlyphRed2 = new PinElement({
  background: "#EB3324",
  borderColor: "#EB3324"
});

const pinGlyphYellow1 = new PinElement({
  background: "#FFFD55",
  borderColor: "#FFFD55"
});

const pinGlyphYellow2 = new PinElement({
  background: "#FFFD55",
  borderColor: "#FFFD55"
});
```

And then you put each of them as a value in the `content` props in each of the `AdvancedMarker`:

```
const L2083875 = { lat: 17.1010277, lng: -89.0770841 };
const marker0 = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
  position: L2083875,
  map: map,
  content: pinGlyphRed1.element
});

const L615687 = { lat: 17.1074, lng: -89.07398 };
const marker1 = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
  position: L615687,
  map: map,
  content: pinGlyphRed2.element
});

const L614723 = { lat: 17.09582, lng: -89.06938 };
const marker2 = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
  position: L614723,
  map: map,
  content: pinGlyphYellow1.element
});

const L5421822 = { lat: 17.0835327, lng: -89.0732431 };
const marker3 = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
  position: L5421822,
  map: map,
  content: pinGlyphYellow2.element
});
```

With that, the color should be properly assigned for each Marker.

### Here's the full code snippet for reference

```js
async function initMap() {
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement, PinElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary(
    "marker"
  );
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 17.0969451, lng: -89.0734218 },
    zoom: 13,
    mapId: "my_map"
  });

const pinGlyphRed1 = new PinElement({
  background: "#EB3324",
  borderColor: "#EB3324"
});

const pinGlyphRed2 = new PinElement({
  background: "#EB3324",
  borderColor: "#EB3324"
});

const pinGlyphYellow1 = new PinElement({
  background: "#FFFD55",
  borderColor: "#FFFD55"
});

const pinGlyphYellow2 = new PinElement({
  background: "#FFFD55",
  borderColor: "#FFFD55"
});

const L2083875 = { lat: 17.1010277, lng: -89.0770841 };
const marker0 = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
  position: L2083875,
  map: map,
  content: pinGlyphRed1.element
});

const L615687 = { lat: 17.1074, lng: -89.07398 };
const marker1 = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
  position: L615687,
  map: map,
  content: pinGlyphRed2.element
});

const L614723 = { lat: 17.09582, lng: -89.06938 };
const marker2 = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
  position: L614723,
  map: map,
  content: pinGlyphYellow1.element
});

const L5421822 = { lat: 17.0835327, lng: -89.0732431 };
const marker3 = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
  position: L5421822,
  map: map,
  content: pinGlyphYellow2.element
});
}

initMap = initMap();
```

```css
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */
#map {
  height: 100vh;
}

/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

[class$="api-load-alpha-banner"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Default Advanced Marker</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- prettier-ignore -->
    <script>(g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})
        ({key: "AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk", v: "beta"});</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with when I needed to use a pin element *n* times.

Just define the pin element when you set the marker's content:

```js
const marker0 = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
position: L2083875, 
map: map, 
content: new PinElement({
    background: "#FFFD55",
    borderColor: "#FFFD55",
  }).element,
});
```