Map pin background color 1st pin marker dissapears (or only last one is displayed)
I believe the answer marked as accepted i not correct - scroll down there is a better solution offered by Christian Robles

I have the code below, the moment I place the second marker the 1st one is not rendered - Im stumped - if I remove the content: pinBackground.element both is rendered again
const pinBackground = new PinElement({
  background: "#FBBC04",
});

new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map,
        title: 'wittebergstudio',
        content: pinBackground.element,
    position: {
      lat: -28.507,
      lng: 27.933
    }
  });

new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map,
        title: 'rusendalcottages',
        content: pinBackground.element,
    position: {
      lat: -28.506,
      lng: 27.940
    }
  });

different color pins/marker

Hi, please see formatting help

https://jsfiddle.net/Lgnojw0z/1/

@pierpy thanx going thru it now - managed to get a jsfiddle going showing the problem with unique declarations for the markers

I have found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76511497/showing-multiple-advancedmarkerelements-with-custom-content but just cant believe it is that stupid?
